# html css alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

Please refer the below code. I want the boxes for Blue and all other color to be stretched. I mean it should start and end with the border of Styles and Colors.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Component5 colors</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .theoneclicked {
                background-color:#b0c4de;
            }
            ul {
                display: block;
                list-style: none;               
            }
            ul#nav_top {
                width:100px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            li#nav_top1, li#colors {
                width:100px;
                border: 1px solid black;        
                display: block;

            }

             li#nav_mid1 {
                border: 1px solid black;

             }
            a {
                text-decoration:none;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="nav_top">
            <li id="nav_top1"><span class="heading"><a href="comp5.html">Styles</a></span></li>
            <li id="colors"><span class="theoneclicked"><a href="colors.html">Colors</a></span></li>
                <ul id="nav_mid">
                    <li id="nav_mid1">
                        Blue                        
                    </li>
                    <li id="nav_mid1"> Orange</li>
                    <li id="nav_mid1">Green</li>
                </ul>
            <li id="images"><span class="nav">Images</span></li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question some more?  Even after looking at your code, it's not easy to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want the borders for the colors to start from the begining i mean where it starts for Styles and Colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your HTML is invalid. A nested `ul` element should be contained within an `li`. Also, you can't repeat `nav_mid1` as an ID. You'll need to use a class for multiple elements.

Changing the markup and CSS to something the following solves your problem. Notice I'm adding some padding to the left of the nested UL as it's obviously a subgroup of 'Colors'.

```
<ul id="nav_top">
            <li id="nav_top1"><span class="heading"><a href="comp5.html">Styles</a></span></li>
            <li id="colors"><span class="theoneclicked"><a href="colors.html">Colors</a></span></li>
    <li>
                <ul id="nav_mid">
                    <li class="nav_mid1">
                        Blue                        
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav_mid1"> Orange</li>
                    <li class="nav_mid1 last">Green</li>
                </ul>
</li>
            <li id="images"><span class="nav">Images</span></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
            ul#nav_top {
                width: 100px;
                display: block;
                list-style: none;               
            }
            ul ul {
padding-left: 10px;}
            ul#nav_top li {

                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            li#nav_top1, li#colors {

                display: block;

            }

             ul#nav_mid li {
               border-width: 0 0 1px 0;


             }
#nav_mid li.last {
    border-bottom: none;
}
            a {
                text-decoration:none;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all change the id's to classes.  The "id" attribute should be used as a unique identifier on the page.
e.g.

```
<li id="nav_top1">
```

becomes

```
<li class="nav_top1">
```

Then change the #'s for .'s in the styles.

e.g

```
ul#nav_top {
```

becomes:

```
ul.nav_top {
```

Finally add the following:

```
ul.nav_mid
{
    padding-left:0;
}
```

This works in Firefox but I wouldn't like to bet if IE behaves with just this.

You should also wrap the nested ul list in an li element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to (un)set some margins and paddings on the `ul`s to do what you want. Setting `list-style:none` is not enough, as it still has margins to it.